# jQuery - Event of button added to div tag not fired

Tags: jquery

I am using `SmartCart.js` script to add the products from one div tag to another, but when I running this code the event to Add Product button is not fired. Why?

```
var HTML = '<div class="scProductListItem">'+
           '<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">'+
           '<tr>'+
           '<td rowspan="3"><img width="100px" src="http://webscopia.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Google.plus-get-an-invite-from-me.jpg" alt="Not availabel" /></td>'+
           '<td><strong><span id="prod_name'+'test'+'">'+'detail_product[0]'+'</span></strong></td>'+
           '</tr>'+
           '<tr>'+
           '<td>'+
           '<input type="button" rel="'+'test'+'" class="scItemButton scBtn" value="Add Product">'+
           '</td>'+
           '</tr>'+
           '</table>'+
           '<input type="button" value="TestButton" name="Test" onclick="Alert()"/>'+
           '</div>';

$('#sc_productlist').append($(HTML));
```

Add Product. These button's event I am not able to receive.

Comment: How and when is an event handler attached to the *Add Product* button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `onclick` event after appending the HTML to your div or you can use the jQuery *[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)* function to bind the event.

Comment: he don't need to. He can use onclick in html() too

Comment: It's the `click` event. `onclick` is only the name of the property/attribute.

Comment: yes it is .but he has not added any event for add product button

Answer (score 0):

Alert() is not a valid function

alert(**''**); is a valid function

Comment: Unless `Alert` is a function defined elsewhere in the OPs code.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: sure, I know.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have any event specified for that button. Try to add an `onclick` event:

```
'<input type="button" rel="'+'test'+'" class="scItemButton scBtn" value="Add Product" onclick="alert(\'Add product\');">'+
```

If you have added an event using jQuery, then it doesn't work because you only add the event to the element that exist at that time. You would have to add the event to the new button after creating it, or use the [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method to add an event handler to a parent element that already exists:

```
$('#sc_productlist').delegate('.scItemButton', 'click', function(){
  // code to handle the event
});
```